# Triggering Ajax event when an object changes its state

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a small university project in which I have to show how certain algorithms work. Decided to use JSF for a simple webapp and save all the algorithm generated data into a database.

I thought to myself 'hey, it would be cool if I can show the user how the algorithm works step by step, nothing fancy, just plain formatted text that changes when the algorithm does its thing. An output text field with Ajax should get the work done!', but I can't quite get my head around a certain problem. Ajax triggers when a certain event occurs, like 'click' or 'keyup', but is there a way to make it trigger when an object in my ManagedBean class changes?

Don't know if I explained well enough, so here's an example of what I want to do:

1. An ArrayList in the ManagedBean is empty, the outputtext prints out nothing
2. After a certain amount of time, a new object is saved in the ArrayList, Ajax triggers and the outputtext prints out its onString()
3. After a certain amount of time again, the same object that was printed out before changes, Ajax triggers and the outputtext changes accordingly

I'm sorry if the problem isn't quite clear, tried describing it to the best of my ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe isn't classic, client-triggered AJAX anymore but known as [server-sent events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) (SSE). They're usually implemented using long-polling (periodic client requests that only get an answer if there's a server-side event).

Your favorite JSF toolkit probably supports it under the name "Push". Here's a [Primefaces example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/counter.xhtml).

However, for your simple use case I'd suggest using *polling* instead. See [this example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml). The main difference is that your server side logic switches to keep a list of "to be displayed" strings/ids/objects. When your browser client polls the server (the listener method gets called), assign the first item to a `String` field in a backing bean and have your client re-render an area where this `String` is shown.

Note that you can do this in plain JSF-2, there's no need for Primefaces.